# Power series representation of $(x+a)/(x^2+a^2)$

Tags: calculus, power-series

What is the power series representation of 
$$\frac{x+a}{x^2+a^2}$$ where $a>0$?

What's its interval of convergence?

Here's what I did

$$\frac{x+a}{a^2} \frac{ 1}{x^2/a^2 + 1}$$ then  $$ \frac{1}{x^2/a^2 + 1}  = \sum (-1)^n \frac{ 1}{a^ (2n)}  x^{2n}$$

then multiply by $(x+a)/a^2$ which will lead to two separate sums. Then there seems no way to combine them.

Comment: Have you made any attempts to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $$\dfrac{1}{x^2+a^2} = \dfrac{1}{a^2}\cdot \dfrac{1}{1+\left(\dfrac{x}{a}\right)^2}=\dfrac{1}{a^2}\cdot \left(1-\left(\dfrac{x}{a}\right)^2 + ...\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Lets extend this question to the complex plane:
$$\frac{z+a}{z^2+a^2}$$
It is clear that the denominator is singular for $z=\sqrt{-a^2}=ia$

Thus, the [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) is than $|z|=a$, since there are no other singularities,

Therefore, the convergence interval on the reals is the segment $(-a,a)$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x+a}{x^2+a^2}=\frac{2a^2}{a+x}-a+x$$
$$\frac{2a}{1+\frac{x}{a}}-a+x$$
by using the geometric series
$$2a(1-\frac{x}{a}+(\frac{x}{a})^2-.....)-a+x$$
$$a-x+\frac{2x^2}{a}-\frac{2x^3}{a^2}+.....$$

Comment: Isn't the RHS of the first equation equal to the reciprocal of the LHS?